# How do I use a String object as an index for an Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the names of Excel files I want to open in an array. Can I use those String objects as the workbook index?

For example:

```
nameText = "Revenue.xlsx"

Set myValues = Workbooks(nameText).Worksheets(1).Columns("J")
```

I believe I'm running into a problem with
`Workbooks(nameText)` -- what can I do to make that work?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` returns a workbook reference. Use that: `Dim wb as Workbook` > `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigBen has the right answer, but I'll expand it a little bit.

You can create a reference to a workbook by initializing and setting a `Workbook` object, then use that to refer to it. This is generally seen as best practice, because it doesn't require that the workbook is already open, since you open it when assigning to a variable.

`Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open('name of your workbook)`

Then you can refer to that workbook by using `wb`, so `Set myValues = wb.Worksheets(1).Columns("J")`

But in general, if the Workbook is open, you can absolutely use strings to refer to Workbooks and Worksheets by using the filename in the `Index` field.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen and jclasley for the clarification! Is there a way to still access the values in column J without opening the workbook referred to by wb? Or is that necessary to pull the data from it?

Comment: Gotta open it. But you can hide it if you want, just be sure to close it at the end of your code. `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("name of your workbook", Visible:=False)`